# How to convert a string like "28 JUL 1795" to a date with the format of"%B %d, %Y"?

Tags: python, datetime, strftime, strptime

I used following line to transfer my date string but it gave me an error.

```
print datetime.datetime.strptime(arg, '%d %b %Y').date().strftime("%B %d, %Y")
```

> `ValueError: time data '28 JUL 1795' does not match format '%B %d %Y'`

Comment: it'd be helpful if you said which language this is for...

Comment: For this example I get a different error: `ValueError: year=1795 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900`

Comment: [Works for me](http://ideone.com/aJ3bQI). Please provide a short complete program that demonstrates the error.

Comment: your title doesn't match your traceback.  1995 != 1795.

Comment: @roippi And the traceback does not match the code. If any it should be `...does not match format '%d %b %Y'`.

Comment: @user4815162342 The error you posted cannot possible come from the piece of code you posted. How can there be a problem with `'%B %d %Y'` if it doesn't appear anywhere in your code.

Comment: @Hyperboreus You meant to say that to user3324502 :)

Comment: @user4815162342 Sure. Are you brothers?

Comment: @Hyperboreus Aren't we all?

Comment: In my original question the date str was "28 JUL 1795". Somebody changed it. the program works perfectly for dates after 1900. I'm looking for a solution (a function) that works before 1900 too.

Answer (score 2):

This behaviour is not reproduceable. The following works as intended:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('28 JUL 1995', '%d %b %Y').date().strftime('%B %d, %Y')
'July 28, 1995'
```

Maybe your input string is not what you expect it to be.

Comment: That's exactly my program. I'm trying to find a way to do it for before 1900.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

time.strptime("28 JUL 1795", "%d %b %y")

heres a link to strptime method which will convert it for you http://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime

heres a link to a similiar question [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: 1795 is considered %Y. It doesn't work.